# anyone knows how to work orbit control on three js if my p5 canvas have some actual control

Tags: three.js

on my p5 canvas i do set some original control as such:

```
this.mousePressed = function(){
        //check if the playback button has been clicked
        var isButtonClicked = this.playbackButton.hitCheck();
        
        var isMouseInBlockGUI = blockMidHighLow.isMouseInGUI();

        //if not make the visualisation fullscreen
        if(isButtonClicked == false && isMouseInBlockGUI == false){
            let fs = fullscreen();
            fullscreen(!fs);
        }
    };
```

on three js wise, i have some control on the 3d animation, however its not working :

```
 const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, render.domElement);
            controls.enabled = true;
            controls.target.set(1000, 0, 1000);
            controls.update();
```

Comment: `render.domElement`, are you sure there has to be `render`, and not `renderer`?

Comment: oo i did set render as the const but just the fact i dont show it here, the code works fine but i just cant find a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

1. set up a camera
2. set up a renderer
3. use OrbitControl

---

## set up a camera

```js
//Object to store the size of the viewport
const size = {
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
};

//Creates the camera (point of view of the user)
const aspect = size.width / size.height;
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect);
camera.position.z = 15;
camera.position.y = 13;
camera.position.x = 8;
```

## set up a renderer

```js
//Sets up the renderer, fetching the canvas of the HTML
const threeCanvas = document.getElementById("three-canvas");
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: threeCanvas,
    alpha: true
});

renderer.setSize(size.width, size.height);
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
```

## Setup an OrbitControl

```js
//Creates the orbit controls (to navigate the scene)
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, threeCanvas);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.target.set(-2, 0, 0);

//Animation loop
const animate = () => {
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};
```

---

Hope this helps. Thanks

## Learning material

I personally recommend this blog. It's very useful to learn.
https://sbcode.net/threejs/orbit-controls/

```js
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
import Stats from 'three/examples/jsm/libs/stats.module'

const scene = new THREE.Scene()
scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(5))

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
)
camera.position.z = 2

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
```